# Error rebuilding RetroArch around ffmpeg

Tags: retropie

I was trying to get ffmpeg on RetroPie and I got to rebuilding RetroArch. However, I got this log:

= = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
        Installing dependencies for 'retroarch' : RetroArch - frontend to the libretro emulator cores - required by all lr-* emulators
        = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =

```
    /home/pi/RetroPie-Setup/tmp/build/retroarch /home/pi/RetroPie-Setup

    = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
    Getting sources for 'retroarch' : RetroArch - frontend to the libretro emulator cores - required by all lr-* emulators
    = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =

    Already up-to-date.
    /home/pi/RetroPie-Setup
    /home/pi/RetroPie-Setup/tmp/build/retroarch /home/pi/RetroPie-Setup

    = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
    Building 'retroarch' : RetroArch - frontend to the libretro emulator cores - required by all lr-* emulators
    = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =

    Checking operating system ... Linux 
    Checking for suitable working C compiler ... /usr/bin/gcc works
    Checking for suitable working C++ compiler ... /usr/bin/g++ works
    Checking for pkg-config ... /usr/bin/pkg-config
    Checking for availability of switch -std=gnu99 in /usr/bin/gcc ... yes
    Checking for availability of switch -Wno-unused-result in /usr/bin/gcc ... yes
    Checking for availability of switch -Wno-unused-variable in /usr/bin/gcc ... yes
    Checking function sd_get_machine_names in -lsystemd ... no
    Checking presence of package bcm_host ... 1
    Checking presence of package brcmegl ... 10
    Checking function ass_library_init in -lass ... no
    Checking function pthread_create in -lpthread ... no
    Checking function dlopen in -ldl ... no
    Checking function socket in -lc ... no
    Warning: All networking features have been disabled.
    Checking function fcntl in -lc ... no
    Checking function getopt_long in -lc ... no
    Error: Dynamic loading of libretro is enabled, but your platform does not appear to have dlopen(), use --disable-dynamic or --with-libretro="-lretro".
    Makefile:10: config.mk: No such file or directory
    rm -rf obj-unix
    rm -f retroarch
    rm -f *.d
    Makefile:10: config.mk: No such file or directory
    config.mk is outdated or non-existing. Run ./configure again.
    Makefile:182: recipe for target 'config.mk' failed
    make: *** [config.mk] Error 1
    /home/pi/RetroPie-Setup
    Could not successfully build retroarch - RetroArch - frontend to the libretro emulator cores - required by all lr-* emulators (/home/pi/RetroPie-Setup/tmp/build/retroarch/retroarch not found).
```

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

You should read https://docs.libretro.com/compilation/linux-and-bsd/ the dependencies are satisfied with :

> apt-get -y install build-essential libxkbcommon-dev zlib1g-dev libfreetype6-dev libegl1-mesa-dev libgles2-mesa-dev libgbm-dev nvidia-cg-toolkit nvidia-cg-dev libavcodec-dev libsdl2-dev libsdl-image1.2-dev libxml2-dev yasm

May be you could be interested by http://www.lakka.tv/ it is said to be the retroarch image for raspberry pie.

Comment: Will try when I get home, but emulationstation is fine for me. If I get a second/third Rpi3, I might try lakka.

Comment: not working (this is just filler)